# working with UIautomator 2.0 and Android Studio 2.x

Tags: android-uiautomator

I was working with uiautomator 1.0.1 using eclispe and generating jar files and using in my setup.
Can anyone point to appropriate source where I can get step by step procedure for switching to Uiautomator 2.0 with Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

To use the Android Testing Support Library in your Gradle project, add these dependencies in your build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4'
  // Set this dependency to use JUnit 4 rules
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4'
  // Set this dependency to build and run Espresso tests
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'
  // Set this dependency to build and run UI Automator tests
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.2'
}
```

Also you need to set the JUnitRunner as the default test instrumentation runner in your Gradle project (UI Automator 2.0 uses **android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner** instead of **android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner**).

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
       testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
}
```

For more details, follow the link [here](http://testdroid.com/tech/how-to-get-started-with-ui-automator-2-0).

Comment: Actually UiAutomator can be used with any test runner. It doesn't have to be AndroidJUnitRunner - you can also use InstrumentationTestRunner for example.

Comment: As far as I know, 'InstrumentationTestRunner class',only supports JUnit 3 tests in comparison with 'AndroidJUnitRunner class' that lets you run JUnit 3 or JUnit 4-style test classes. However, I agree that UIAutomator can be used with any test runner.