# How to build a Java Jar file and run UIAutomator on an Android device?

Tags: java, android, jar, android-uiautomator

I remember back at Motorola we were able to compile a Jar file, push the jar file onto the Android Device, and through cmd Prompt execute the jar file and call specific class files to run automation on the device.
Problem is we had libraries already built and I didn't get a full understanding of how it worked. All I remember was compiling the jar file through command prompt, then pushing it into the phone and calling the jar file thats on the phone with the name of the method that needed to be executed. then the phone started doing its thing.
Does any one know how I can do this, or what the method is called so I can start researching it?

Comment: Relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39501931/working-with-uiautomator-2-0-and-android-studio-2-x

Answer (score 0):

The method you mentioned (pushing a jar) was used by previous versions and it's no longer required.

You can read the details about the new Testing Support Library and UiAutomator [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/testing-support-library/index.html#UIAutomator).

Basically. you create an APK with your tests, install it on the device under test and run the tests, which can be accomplished using `adb` so you don't need other external tools.

Comment: How come this isn't supported? I need to be able to compile a file and run it with out help from eclipse or external packaging.